# How to identify date within a specific range from multiple columns of a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, date, multiple-columns, matching

I have a very large dataframe with > 300 date columns (and >100,000 rows). Each row also contains an 'index date'. For each row, I want to identify whether any of the subsequent date columns contain a date which is within 6 months of the index date. I then want an output of a separate column which tells me WHICH of the date columns for that row contained the date which was within 6 months of the index date. I'm afraid I haven't really tried anything meaningful as am not sure where to start but I've provided a simplified example of what I am trying to achieve below.
I would be very grateful for any ideas please!

Example dataframe

```
library(dplyr)

example <- data.frame(
'index_date' = as.Date(c('2006/01/01', '2007/01/01', '2008/01/01', '2009/01/01', '2010/01/01')),
'date_1' = as.Date(c('2006/02/01', '2004/01/01', '2004/01/01', '2004/01/01', '2004/01/01')),
'date_2' = as.Date(c('2011/02/01', '2006/12/01', '2005/01/01', '2005/01/01', '2005/01/01')),
'date_3' = as.Date(c('2012/02/01', '2012/12/01', '2012/01/01', '2012/01/01', '2010/03/01')),
'date_4' = as.Date(c('2013/03/01', '2012/12/01', '2012/01/01', '2012/01/01', '2010/06/01'))) %>% 

# now create the `date_range` columns for each row. `start_range` is 6 months prior to the index date (182.6 days) and `end_range` is 6 months (182.6 days) after the index date

 mutate(start_range = (index_date - 182.6),
         end_range = (index_date + 182.6))
```

This produces the following dataframe

```
  index_date     date_1     date_2     date_3     date_4 start_range  end_range
1 2006-01-01 2006-02-01 2011-02-01 2012-02-01 2006-03-01  2005-07-02 2006-07-02
2 2007-01-01 2004-01-01 2006-12-01 2012-12-01 2012-12-01  2006-07-02 2007-07-02
3 2008-01-01 2004-01-01 2005-01-01 2012-01-01 2012-01-01  2007-07-02 2008-07-01
4 2009-01-01 2004-01-01 2005-01-01 2012-01-01 2012-01-01  2008-07-02 2009-07-02
5 2010-01-01 2004-01-01 2005-01-01 2010-03-01 2010-06-01  2009-07-02 2010-07-02
```

Now what I would like to do is create a further column called `matching_date` which, for each row, tells me which of the date columns are within the date range. Note that row 5 contains two potential dates within range (`date_3` and `date_4`), so ideally I also need to incorporate a function which identifies the date which is closest to the index date (in this case it would be `date_3`).

Desired output

```
  index_date     date_1     date_2     date_3     date_4 start_range  end_range matching_date
1 2006-01-01 2006-02-01 2011-02-01 2012-02-01 2006-03-01  2005-07-02 2006-07-02        date_1
2 2007-01-01 2004-01-01 2006-12-01 2012-12-01 2012-12-01  2006-07-02 2007-07-02        date_2
3 2008-01-01 2004-01-01 2005-01-01 2012-01-01 2012-01-01  2007-07-02 2008-07-01            NA
4 2009-01-01 2004-01-01 2005-01-01 2012-01-01 2012-01-01  2008-07-02 2009-07-02            NA
5 2010-01-01 2004-01-01 2005-01-01 2010-03-01 2010-06-01  2009-07-02 2010-07-02        date_3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your records are uniquely identified by `index_date`, you may go with this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
example <- data.frame(
'index_date' = as.Date(c('2006/01/01', '2007/01/01', '2008/01/01', '2009/01/01', '2010/01/01')),
'date_1' = as.Date(c('2006/02/01', '2004/01/01', '2004/01/01', '2004/01/01', '2004/01/01')),
'date_2' = as.Date(c('2011/02/01', '2006/12/01', '2005/01/01', '2005/01/01', '2005/01/01')),
'date_3' = as.Date(c('2012/02/01', '2012/12/01', '2012/01/01', '2012/01/01', '2010/03/01')),
'date_4' = as.Date(c('2013/03/01', '2012/12/01', '2012/01/01', '2012/01/01', '2010/06/01'))) %>% 

# now create the `date_range` columns for each row. `start_range` is 6 months prior to the index date (182.6 days) and `end_range` is 6 months (182.6 days) after the index date

 mutate(start_range = (index_date - 182.6),
         end_range = (index_date + 182.6))

example_long <- 
  example |> 
  pivot_longer(
    cols=starts_with("date"),
    names_to="vars",
    values_to="dates") |> 
  mutate(diff = abs(dates - index_date)) |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(matching_date = ifelse(between(dates, start_range, end_range), vars, NA)) |> 
  filter(!is.na(matching_date)) |> 
  group_by(index_date) |> 
  mutate(tie = which(diff == min(diff))) |> 
  filter(tie == row_number()) |> 
  select(index_date, matching_date)

left_join(example, example_long)
#> Joining, by = "index_date"
#>   index_date     date_1     date_2     date_3     date_4 start_range  end_range
#> 1 2006-01-01 2006-02-01 2011-02-01 2012-02-01 2013-03-01  2005-07-02 2006-07-02
#> 2 2007-01-01 2004-01-01 2006-12-01 2012-12-01 2012-12-01  2006-07-02 2007-07-02
#> 3 2008-01-01 2004-01-01 2005-01-01 2012-01-01 2012-01-01  2007-07-02 2008-07-01
#> 4 2009-01-01 2004-01-01 2005-01-01 2012-01-01 2012-01-01  2008-07-02 2009-07-02
#> 5 2010-01-01 2004-01-01 2005-01-01 2010-03-01 2010-06-01  2009-07-02 2010-07-02
#>   matching_date
#> 1        date_1
#> 2        date_2
#> 3          <NA>
#> 4          <NA>
#> 5        date_3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Claudio, I got this to work well for my real data also!

Comment: Looking back at my code I realize that in case of "ties" with dates coming *before* the index date it would select that one even if it was more distant than other dates. I corrected the code.

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `dplyr`.

- Find the rows that fall into the range.
- Get the minimum distance of dates to midpoint of the ranges (`index_date`).
- Match the minimum distance between `Min` and `index_date` of the matching range `Is` with the associated colname.

```
library(dplyr)

example %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Is = any(across(date_1:date_4, ~ .x >= start_range & .x <= end_range)), 
         Min = which.min(across(date_1:date_4, ~ abs(.x - index_date))), 
         matching_date = if_else(Is, 
           unlist(list(colnames(across(date_1:date_4))))[Min], NA_character_), 
         Is = NULL, Min = NULL) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  print(Inf)
# A tibble: 5 × 8
  index_date date_1     date_2     date_3     date_4     start_range end_range 
  <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>      <date>    
1 2006-01-01 2006-02-01 2011-02-01 2012-02-01 2013-03-01 2005-07-02  2006-07-02
2 2007-01-01 2004-01-01 2006-12-01 2012-12-01 2012-12-01 2006-07-02  2007-07-02
3 2008-01-01 2004-01-01 2005-01-01 2012-01-01 2012-01-01 2007-07-02  2008-07-01
4 2009-01-01 2004-01-01 2005-01-01 2012-01-01 2012-01-01 2008-07-02  2009-07-02
5 2010-01-01 2004-01-01 2005-01-01 2010-03-01 2010-06-01 2009-07-02  2010-07-02
  matching_date
  <chr>        
1 date_1       
2 date_2       
3 NA           
4 NA           
5 date_3
```

##### Data

```
example <- structure(list(index_date = structure(c(13149, 13514, 13879, 
14245, 14610), class = "Date"), date_1 = structure(c(13180, 12418, 
12418, 12418, 12418), class = "Date"), date_2 = structure(c(15006, 
13483, 12784, 12784, 12784), class = "Date"), date_3 = structure(c(15371, 
15675, 15340, 15340, 14669), class = "Date"), date_4 = structure(c(15765, 
15675, 15340, 15340, 14761), class = "Date"), start_range = structure(c(12966.4, 
13331.4, 13696.4, 14062.4, 14427.4), class = "Date"), end_range = structure(c(13331.6, 
13696.6, 14061.6, 14427.6, 14792.6), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. When I run this same code though with the example above I get an error message which seems to imply that it doesn't like that it isn't a numeric variable: Apologies if I am missing something obvious - please could you advise? Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `is = any(across(date_1:date_4, ~.x >= start_range & .x <= end_range))`.
ℹ The error occurred in row 1.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables.

Comment: @Naomi You mean you run it on the given example here in your question and that gives you the error?

Comment: @Naomi Maybe restart your environment and run it on a fresh R session.

Comment: yes exactly - copying exactly the example script I posted above to create the 'example' dataframe and then your script....can't quite figure out what I am doing wrong. p.s sorry just seen your tip about restarting - I will try that!

Comment: @Naomi Try the first operation alone to see if that works `example %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(date_1 >= start_range & date_1 <= end_range) %>% print(Inf)`. If this works the whole code should also work. If that fails maybe check the version of `dplyr` and maybe update it and try again after a relaunch of R. Nothing really experimental code-wise :)

Comment: Hi Andre. The first operation which you posted above does work but then I get the same error as before when trying to run the whole chunk of code. Not sure why. I tried updating dplyr, relaunching R etc. In the meantime I have got the solution below to work for me. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Naomi Thanks for your replies. I also don't know why this doesn't work for you. Let's keep it and see if it resolves later.